# vectorize join condition in pandas

Tags: pandas

This code is working correctly as expected. But it takes a lot of time for large dataframes.

```
for i in excel_df['name_of_college_school'] :
    for y in mysql_df['college_name'] :
        if SequenceMatcher(None,  i.lower(), y.lower() ).ratio() > 0.8:
            excel_df.loc[excel_df['name_of_college_school'] == i, 'dupmark4'] = y
```

I guess, I can not use a function on join clause to compare values like this.
How do I vectorize this?

---

Update:

Is it possible to update with the highest score? This loop will overwrite the earlier match and it is possible that the earlier match was more relevant than current one.

Comment: Let's say for i=5, y iloc at 60 condition meets, and y iloc 90 also meets, this latest one would overwrite the loc setting, isn't it? Are you sure, that's intended?

Comment: Code looks good... but what about your data? You're a user with nearly 10k rep... surely you must understand we cannot really help without a [mcve]...

Comment: @Zero ideally if the ratio value of iloc 90 is higher than 60 then it should replace.

Comment: Yea, I thought so, your approach doesn't solve it however.

Comment: `fuzzywuzzy` may help

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is fuzzy merging.

```
a = excel_df.as_matrix()
b = mysql_df.as_matrix()
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if SequenceMatcher(None,  
               i[college_index_a].lower(), y[college_index_b].lower() ).ratio() > 0.8:
            i[dupmark_index] = j
```

Never use loc in a loop, it has a huge overhead. And btw, get the index of the respective columns, (the numerical one). Use this -

```
df.columns.get_loc("college name")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid one of the loops using `apply` and instead of *MxN* `.loc` operations, now it'll be *M* operations.

```
for y in mysql_df['college_name']:
    match = excel_df['name_of_college_school'].apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(
                                            None, x.lower(), y.lower()).ratio() > 0.8)
    excel_df.loc[match, 'dupmark4'] = y
```